# Google Calendar Service - Response Comments?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-apps, heading

Is anyone aware of a way to record the 'notes' section of the reply?

[image: Example]

Where the alphabet is listed in the above example.

I'm currently using this to get the calendar headings:

```
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "ID","Email","Status","Name"]]
```

But would love a way to record the comments as well, so if anyone has any ideas that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. Use [events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#top_of_page) to retrieve the [attendees[].comment](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) which contains the notes of the response.

Use the [Try-It](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it) to try this now.

Here's a sample note from my response to an event invitation using the Try-it:

```
"attendees": [
    {
    "email": "invitedguest@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Guest Helios",
    "responseStatus": "accepted",
    "comment": "This is a note from Helios"
    }
```

Additional note:

When using the Try-it, remember that calendarId is always your email and eventId can be retrieved in the event window, More Actions then Troubleshooting Info.